# Why can we not write: $\lim_{x \to 0}(-\frac{1}{x})=-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, infinity

I was skimming through a few books on calculus, and came across the statement that:

we cannot write out this limit as $+\infty$ or $-\infty$  like so: $\lim_{x \to 0}(-\frac{1}{x})=-\infty$, only as $\lim_{x \to 0}(\frac{1}{x})=\infty$. The argument provided was that its a **matter of agreement**.

Although, it's considered perfectly fine to write this equation likeso: $\lim_{x \to 0}(-\frac{1}{x^2})=-\infty$

My question is whether anyone else has written it in opposition to the statement above, and what is meant by "matter of agreement", and why it may be as such.

Or might it just be the authors own biased opinion, for whatever reason?

I personally see nothing wrong with introducing $+\infty \space or -\infty$ given that it helps to recognise further meaning in supporting your rationale for proving a theorem.

Here's an image of the page where it's taken from:
[image]

Reference:
Fort, T. (1951) Calculus. pg 50.

Your comments are most welcome.

Comment: The limit in the title is true provided you approach $0$ from the right, i.e., along positive numbers.

Comment: As far as I’m concerned, it is simply incorrect to write $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x=\infty$: that limit does not exist even in the extended real numbers. What **is** true is that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac1x=+\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac1x=-\infty$.

Comment: What's different about the graph of $\frac{1}{x}$ vs $\frac{1}{x^2}$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Indeed, which is why I found the statement rather strange.

Comment: I agree. Without further context, the text is simply wrong.

Comment: The text is wrong, unless there was something before or after the image which justifies it's usage.

Comment: @AdamRubinson No justification beforehand, so the author is wrong.

Comment: What they simply mean is that the limit of $1/x$ is $\pm\infty.$ This is what is written as $\infty,$ and hence is a matter of agreement since the limit technically doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, the "matter of agreement" means that denoting $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=-\infty
$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0-}f(x)=+\infty
$$ which do not agree.

Alternatively, the definition of "$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=-\infty$" says that

> for every $M>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-0|<\delta$ implies $f(x)<-M$.

But this is impossible in the case when $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Without entering the limit definition, ask yourself: how do you approach to $ 0 $?

**First**

You can take $x=0.00000000...1$, then what do you get?

$$\dfrac 1x=\dfrac {1}{0.00000000...1}=100000000...\longrightarrow \color {red} {\text{positive infinity}}$$

**Second**

You can take $x=-0.00000000...1$, then what do you get?

$$\dfrac 1x=\dfrac {1}{-0.00000000...1}=-100000000...\longrightarrow \color {blue} {\text{negative infinity}}$$

So, you get two different result:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac1x=+ \infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac1x=- \infty$$

What will we do now?Which do you think is right?  Unfortunately, none of limits are correct. Because, you get two different results. This is called right and left limits in mathematics.  These must be equal for the limit to exist. So, we must say "limit doesn't exist."

But, note that this limit is correct:

$$\boxed {\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{|x|} =\infty}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you write, $\ \lim_{x \to 0^+}(-\frac{1}{x})=-\infty,\ $ then I would know what you mean, although I may or may not point out that it is more "proper" to say that the limit " diverges to $\ -\infty $", but some people may say that this is just me being pedantic and I think this is a fair opinion also.

However, saying that $\ \lim_{x \to 0}(-\frac{1}{x})=-\infty,\ $ is just **incorrect**, because

$\ \lim_{x \to 0^-}(-\frac{1}{x})=\infty \neq -\infty = \lim_{x \to 0^+}(-\frac{1}{x}). $